# Only left channel being converted to mono

Tags: sound, 20.04, pulseaudio, mono

When I plug my low-quality mono earphones into my motherboard (green audio slot), I hear sound in both the left and the right earplugs.

Now if the sound being played is also mono then this is fine, however when the sound is stereo then the left channel of the stereo sound is what's being played in both the earplugs.

Instead of selecting the left channel, it'd make more sense if they were merged and then were being played.

How can I achieve this? More importantly, is there a way for my computer to auto detect that the device plugged in recieves mono output and do this automatically? So that when I plug it out and plug in something else with stereo output (like my speakers), then this problem is no longer there?

Comment: The left channel was deemed (*historically*) to be treated as the MONO signal if a stereo signal was to be used only as mono. What you're describing is actually following *historical* standards... A stereo signal was often *remastered* joining L&R signals creating a mono-only track (which is what you really want I gather).

Comment: I see. I had no idea! Is there documentation on why this has been the historical behavior? I think windows behaves differently.

Comment: Nah sorry I'm not aware of documentation; what I'm describing is what most mono tape recorders/players (*pre-digital*) did when you put in a stereo cassette., even many expensive stereo deck players (though yamaha & some units provided a switch that would join signals, but that only existed on some decks). I suspect it was just convention (fear of consumers detecting bleed-thru of channels and loosing the *fidelity* rep, but also simplify); I'm talking late 60s thru early 80s; both valve [pre-transistor] & early transistor cassette decks & amplifiers (which did it for vinyl records too)